# How to store my own Timestamp in Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I would like to store a DateTime as a Timestamp in Firestore. I would like to be able to store it so that it appears like that in my db.

[image]

I don't want a workaround by storing the millisecondsSinceEpoch or a string version of the date. I really want a timestamp object.

I know it is possible to store the server time stamp like that by storing `FieldValue.serverTimeStamp()`. But I would like to set my own date, not the one of the server.

When I save a Timestamp object (from `package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/timestamp.dart`) it is automatically converted to an int.

I'll appreciate any help.

Edit :

I use the freezed package to handle my classes. I am required to use the TimestampConverter otherwise the compiler says :

```
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `orderDate`.
To support the type `Timestamp` you can:
* Use `JsonConverter`
```

Here is the data transfer object of my OrderData class.

```
@freezed
abstract class OrderDataDto implements _$OrderDataDto {
  const OrderDataDto._();

  const factory OrderDataDto({
    required String uid,
    @TimestampConverter() required Timestamp orderDate,
  }) = _OrderDataDto;

  factory OrderDataDto.fromDomain(OrderData order) {
    return OrderDataDto(
      uid: order.uid.getOrCrash(),
      orderDate: Timestamp.fromDate( order.orderDate), // Because order.orderDate it a [DateTime]
    );
  }

  OrderData toDomain() {
    return OrderData(
      uid: UniqueId.fromUniqueString(uid),
      orderDate: orderDate,
    );
  }

  factory OrderDataDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$OrderDataDtoFromJson(json);

  factory OrderDataDto.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final json = Map<String, dynamic>.from(doc.data()! as Map);
    final ret = OrderDataDto.fromJson(json).copyWith(uid: doc.id);
    return ret;
  }
}
```

```
class TimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<Timestamp, Object> {
  const TimestampConverter();

  @override
  Timestamp fromJson(Object json) {
    return json as Timestamp;
  }

  @override
  Object toJson(Timestamp timestamp) => timestamp;
}
```

Comment: so you only need to store your int value as a timestamp value? or you need to save timestamp with that format?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect. We should be able to reproduce the problem that you described with Timestamp.

Comment: @Royalindo, I want to save a timestamp from my app to firebase. Whether its abstract data type in my app is an int, a date or a string, we don't really care, but I want to store it as a timestamp in firebase. Similar to what you would obtain if you added a new field in a document and would select timestamp.

Comment: Hey, I actually found the issue. I shouldn't cast the Timestamp to an Object in the TimestampConverter.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the issue. I shouldn't be casting the [Timestamp] to [Object] int the TimestampConverter. So by using the next one, it works like a charm.

```
class TimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<Timestamp, Object> {
  const TimestampConverter();

  @override
  Timestamp fromJson(Object json) {
    return json as Timestamp;
  }

  @override
  Object toJson(Timestamp timestamp) => timestamp;
}
```

But a question still remains. Why do I have to use a converter that literally doesn't do anything?